# The Ho-Lee Model (1986)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

### (My question)

I solved the following questions. However, if you know the other solutions, please let me know those along with computation processes. Besides, $W_t$ is a S.B.M.

(Thank you for your help in advance.)

---

### (Cross-link)

I have posted the same question on https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47306/the-ho-lee-model-1986

---

### (Original questions)

Consider a short term interest rate process $(r_t)_{ t \in \mathbb{R}_+ }$ in the Ho-Lee Model with constant coefficients:
\begin{eqnarray}
dr_t = \theta dt + \sigma dW_t
\end{eqnarray} 
and let $P(t, T)$ will denote the arbitrage price of a zero-coupon bond in this model:
\begin{eqnarray}
P(t, T) = E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] 
\end{eqnarray} 
where $t \in [0, T]$.

(1) State the bond pricing PDE satisfied by the function $F(t, x)$ defined via
\begin{eqnarray}
F(t, x) = E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) | r_t=x \right] 
\end{eqnarray} 
where $t \in [0, T]$.

(2) Compute the arbitrage price $F(t, r_t) =P(t, T)$ from its expression of $P(t, T)$ as a conditional expectation.

(3) Check that the function $F(t, x)$ computed in Question (2) does satisfy the PDE derived in Question (1).

---

### (1) My answer

- One can derive the following PDE by Feynman-Kac Theorem.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  F(t, x) &=& E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) | r_t=x \right] \\
  \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) F(t, x) &=& E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_0 r_s ds \right) | r_t=x \right] 
  \end{eqnarray}
- One adapts It$\hat{o}$'s formula the above equation. Here, one has to pay attention that the R.H.S is zero because it is a constant value, namely an expectation value. Moreover, $F(T, x)=1$ by the R.H.S going to $1$ because of $t=T$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && d\left( \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) F(t, x)  \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad = \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \left( -r_t F(t, x) + \partial_t F(t, x) \right) dt \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad  + \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \partial_x F(t, x) dr_t \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  + \frac{1}{2}  \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \partial_{xx} F(t, x) d[r_t] 
  \end{eqnarray}
- One substitutes $r_t$ into the above equation.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && d\left( \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) F(t, x)  \right)  \nonumber \\
  && = \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \left( -r_t F(t, x) + \partial_t F(t, x) \right) dt \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \partial_x F(t, x) \left(  \theta dt + \sigma dW_t \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + \frac{1}{2}  \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \partial_{xx} F(t, x) \sigma^2 dt \\
  && = \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right) \left( -r_t F(t, x) + \partial_t F(t, x) + \theta \partial_x F(t, x) + \frac{1}{2}  \sigma^2 \partial_{xx} F(t, x) \right) dt \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + \exp \left( - \int^t_0 r_s ds \right)   \sigma  \partial_x F(t, x)  dW_t  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Since the coefficient of the drift term is zero due to the martingale property of S.D.E, the following equation is obtained. Here, one has to pay attention to $r_t=x$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && -r_t F(t, x) + \partial_t F(t, x) + \theta \partial_x F(t, x) + \frac{1}{2}  \sigma^2 \partial_{xx} F(t, x) =0 \\
  && -xF(t, x) + \partial_t F(t, x) + \theta \partial_x F(t, x) + \frac{1}{2}  \sigma^2 \partial_{xx} F(t, x) =0
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

### (2) My answer

- Compute S.I.E by the given S.D.E.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  dr_t &=& \theta dt + \sigma dW_t \\
  r_t &=& r_0 + \theta t + \sigma W_t
  \end{eqnarray}
- Let $x=r_t$:
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && F(t, x) \\
  &&= F(t, r_t) \\
  &&= E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) | r_t=x \right] \\
  &&= E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t  \left( r_0 + \theta s + \sigma W_s  \right)  ds\right) | \mathcal{F}_t\right] \\
  &&= E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t  \left( \left( r_0 + \theta t + \sigma W_t\right)+ \theta (s-t) + \sigma( W_s -W_t) \right)  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t\right] \\
  &&= E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t  \left( r_t + \theta (s-t) + \sigma( W_s -W_t) \right)  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t\right] \\
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes $exp$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && \exp \left( - \int^T_t  \left( r_t + \theta (s-t) + \sigma( W_s -W_t) \right)  ds \right) \\
  && \qquad =\exp \left( - r_t \int^T_t  ds \right) \cdot  \exp \left( - \theta \int^T_t  (s-t) ds \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \sigma \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t) ds \right) \\
  && \qquad =\exp \left( - r_t (T-t)  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \cdot  \exp \left( - \theta \frac{1}{2} (T^2- t^2) + \theta t(T-t)  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \sigma \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t) ds \right) \\
  && \qquad =\exp \left( - r_t (T-t)  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \cdot  \exp \left( - \theta (T-t) \left( \frac{1}{2} (T + t) - t\right)  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \sigma \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t) ds \right) \\
  && \qquad =\exp \left( - r_t (T-t)  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \cdot  \exp \left( - \theta (T-t) \left( \frac{1}{2} (T - t) \right)  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \sigma  \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t)ds \right) \\
  && \qquad =\exp \left( - r_t (T-t)  \right)  \cdot  \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2 \ \right)  \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \sigma  \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t) ds \right) \\
  && \qquad =\exp \left( - r_t (T-t)  - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  \right)  \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot \exp \left( - \sigma \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t)  ds \right) \\
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the Expectation.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && F(t, r_t) \\
  &&= E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[ \exp \left( - r_t (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  - \sigma  \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t) ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &&= \exp \left( - r_t (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( - \sigma  \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t)  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] 
  \end{eqnarray}
- One computes the above expectation value as below.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  &&E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( - \sigma  \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t)  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad = E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( - \sigma  \int^T_t  W_{s-t}  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &&   \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad = E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( \int^{T-t}_0  \left(  - \sigma W_s \right)  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, It$\hat{o}$'s formula is applied to the exponent part, and further calculation is performed.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d \left( - \sigma  W_s s \right) &=& - \sigma  W_s ds  -  \sigma s d W_s + \frac{1}{2} 0 d [W_s] \\
  &=& - \sigma   W_s  ds  -  \sigma s d W_s \\
  \int^{T-t}_0 d \left( - \sigma  W_s s \right) &=& \int^{T-t}_0 \left( - \sigma  W_s  \right) ds - \sigma \int^{T-t}_0 s d W_s \\
   - \sigma  W_{T-t}  (T-t)  &=& \int^{T-t}_0 \left( - \sigma  W_s  \right) ds - \sigma \int^{T-t}_0 s d W_s \\
   \int^{T-t}_0 \left( - \sigma  W_s \right) ds  &=& - \sigma  W_{T-t}  (T-t) + \int^{T-t}_0 \sigma s d W_s \\
   &=& - \sigma  (T-t) \int^{T-t}_0 d W_s  + \int^{T-t}_0 \sigma s d W_s \\
   &=& \sigma \int^{T-t}_0 \left( s- (T-t) \right)  d W_s \\
   &=&  \int^{T-t}_0 \left( \sigma \left( s- (T-t) \right) \right)  d W_s \\
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the expectation.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  &&E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( - \sigma  \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t)  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad = E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( \int^{T-t}_0 \left(  - \sigma W_s \right) ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &&   \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad = E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( \int^{T-t}_0 \left(  \sigma \left( s - (T-t)\right) \right)  d W_s  \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &&   \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad = \exp \left( \frac{ \sigma^2}{2} \int^{T-t}_0 \left( s - (T-t) \right)^2 ds \right) \\
  &&   \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad = \exp \left( \frac{ \sigma^2}{2}  \left[ \frac{1}{3} \left( s - (T-t) \right)^3 \right]^{T-t}_0 \right) \\
  &&   \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad = \exp \left( \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the Expectation of the $F(t, r_t)$ equation.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && F(t, r_t) \\
  &&= \exp \left( - r_t (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  \right) \nonumber \\
  &&   \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \cdot E^{ \mathbb{P} } \left[  \exp \left( - \sigma  \int^T_t  ( W_s -W_t)  ds \right) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &&= \exp \left( - r_t (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  \right) \cdot \exp \left( \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right) \\
  &&= \exp \left( - r_t (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

### (3) My answer

- Let $r_t=x$ into $F(t, r_t)$ of (2).
  \begin{eqnarray}
  F(t, x) =  \exp \left( - x (T-t) - \frac{1}{2} \theta (T-t)^2  + \frac{ \sigma^2}{6}  (T-t)^3  \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Then, one reaches the following equations.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \partial_t F(t, x) &=&  \left(  x  + \theta (T-t)  - \frac{ \sigma^2}{2}  (T-t)^2  \right) F(t, x) \\
  \partial_x F(t, x) &=& - (T-t)  F(t, x) \\
  \partial_{xx} F(t, x) &=&  (T-t)^2  F(t, x) \\
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore, one computes the P.D.E of (1). Besides, the terminal condition is $F(T, x)=1$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && -xF(t, x) + \partial_t F(t, x) + \theta \partial_x F(t, x) + \frac{1}{2}  \sigma^2 \partial_{xx} F(t, x) \\
  && \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad = -xF(t, x) \\
  && \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  + \left(  x  + \theta (T-t)  - \frac{ \sigma^2}{2}  (T-t)^2  \right) F(t, x) \\
  && \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad - \theta (T-t)  F(t, x) + \frac{1}{2}  \sigma^2 (T-t)^2  F(t, x) \\
  && \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad = 0
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(Thank you for your help in advance.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will post this  https://quant.stackexchange.com as well.